# postgresql : column does not exist on left join

Tags: sql, postgresql

to get the activity of the user

I have a query that left join product and its reviews and grouping them by reviews_product_id.

```
SELECT product_name, product_description, product_image, count, average_rating, latest_review_date, product_id, user_id
FROM products 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT reviews_product_id, MAX(created_at) AS latest_review_date, COUNT(*), TRUNC(AVG(rating),1) AS average_rating 
    FROM reviews 
    GROUP BY reviews_product_id
  ) reviews on products.product_id = reviews.reviews_product_id
```

This is the returned rows

```
Result: -[ RECORD 1 ]-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
product_name        | Nescafe
product_description | nice.
product_image       | image
count               | 6
average_rating      | 3.5
latest_review_date  | 2021-12-30 14:07:11.158849+08
product_id          | 3
user_id             | 166e0efb-ee3f-47ab-b8c9-5c9b74187ec4

-[ RECORD 2 ]-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

product_name        | Zesto
product_description | So Refreshing!
product_image       | image
count               | 7
average_rating      | 2.4
latest_review_date  | 2021-12-30 14:07:27.917427+08
product_id          | 2
user_id             | 166e0efb-ee3f-47ab-b8c9-5c9b74187ec4
```

data is correct but I want also to filter so the returned rows will output the user who made that review

```
SELECT product_name, product_description, product_image, count, average_rating, latest_review_date, product_id, user_id
FROM products 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT reviews_product_id, MAX(created_at) AS latest_review_date, COUNT(*), TRUNC(AVG(rating),1) AS average_rating 
    FROM reviews 
    GROUP BY reviews_product_id
  ) reviews on products.product_id = reviews.reviews_product_id
WHERE reviews.user_id = '1234';
```

But it's telling me that

> column reviews.user_id does not exist

Comment: You are not returning `user_id` inside the derived table (aka sub-query) named `reviews`. You need to move that `WHERE` clause into the derived table. And besides: that where clause would turn your outer join into an inner join

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried moving the WHERE inside 

(SELECT ... FROM reviews WHERE reviews.user_id = '1234' GROUP BY reviews_product_id) 


But it's not filtering. it always returns the same rows no matter what user_id i put there;

Comment: Well, obviously the outer query won't be changed as you are using an outer join.

Comment: @DaveInoc What is your goal when you are filtering by user? If you want to get only the products, that have a review from the specific user, you should do inner join instead.

Comment: @Eugenij yep that worked! Thanks, guys I learned a lot! I did not know that there is more type of joins. I will practice more

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments the subquery does not return `user_id`. Once you have added that column to the SELECT in subquery, you can add `reviews.user_id = '1234'` to the `on` conditions, as so `on products.product_id = reviews.reviews_product_id and reviews.user_id = '1234'`.

(I know this should have been a comment but I don't have enough reputation to add comments :) Trying to build it up right now.)

Comment: sorry I'm really new with Postgres but yeah I tried adding the user_id on subquery but I always get the error 
"column "reviews.user_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function" 

I don't really know any workaround for this.

Comment: No worries. I missed that too. So basically if u reference any column in select and there is a group by then all those columns in select should be in group by too. From what I understand from your query, maybe you can use `product.user_id` itself ? Correct me if product.user_id values will not be same as reviews.user_id.
OR, this might be complex but what you can try is `WHERE (select r.user_id from reviews r where r.reviews_product_id = reviews.review_product_id) = '1234'`. This would replace the WHERE in the query in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I need to read more about postgres, I was using a different join method.

Replacing left join with inner join worked!

```
SELECT product_name, product_description, product_image, count, average_rating, latest_review_date, product_id, user_id
    FROM products INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT reviews_product_id, MAX(created_at) AS latest_review_date, COUNT(*), TRUNC(AVG(rating),1) AS average_rating FROM reviews WHERE reviews.user_id = '339d1daa-2f66-46b7-b7bd-bdd980039185' GROUP BY reviews_product_id) 
        reviews 
        on products.product_id = reviews.reviews_product_id;
```